# Layout incorrect for UIScrollView that holds a UIImageView after orientation changes in IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiinterfaceorientation

I have setup a `UIScrollView` that holds a `UIImageView` with a `UIImage`. The UIImage that I load into the image view is around 2300x1200 in size and not scaled down as can be zoomed.

The UIScrollView holds a UIImageView that is setup to allow tap/double tap to zoom in and out of the image. I have [followed a tutorial here to create this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content).

The source code for the example can be [downloaded here.](http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/downloads/ScrollViews.zip).

**Issue**
The issue I have is with change of orientation. The views are no longer layed out as expected and offset.

Once the image is downloaded (in my example) I complete the following:

```
[self.mainImageView setImage:image];
self.mainImageView.frame = (CGRect){.origin=CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f), .size=image.size};

// Tell the scroll view the size of the contents
self.mainScrollView.contentSize = image.size;

[self setupScales];
```

I then setupScales as follows:

```
// Set up the minimum & maximum zoom scales
CGRect scrollViewFrame = self.mainScrollView.frame;
CGFloat scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / self.mainScrollView.contentSize.width;
CGFloat scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / self.mainScrollView.contentSize.height;
CGFloat minScale = MIN(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

self.mainScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;
self.mainScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0f;
self.mainScrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

[self centerScrollViewContents];
```

I then centerScrollViewContents as follows:

```
CGSize boundsSize = self.mainScrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = self.mainImageView.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

self.mainImageView.frame = contentsFrame;
```

The scrollView and the imageView are setup with the following:

```
self.mainScrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.mainImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

The scrollView has a constraint to the left/right/top/bottom pinned at 0, and the imageView has no constraints as created manually without. I have tried to run `self.mainScrollView needsUpdateConstraints` in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` but this does not make a difference.

The same issue can be replicated in the example app above when selecting the first option 'Image Zoom' and then changing orientation of the device. I am not sure what is incorrect it appears the frames are set incorrectly. I have tried to run setupScales at different points but this does not appear to change the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the contentSize of the scrollView is reset when the frame changes. I have to set it back to the image size once the rotation is complete.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    // When the orientation is changed the contentSize is reset when the frame changes. Setting this back to the relevant image size
    self.mainScrollView.contentSize = self.mainImageView.image.size;
    // Reset the scales depending on the change of values
    [self setupScales];
}
```

I have setup a repo for anyone that needs this in the future - https://github.com/StuartMorris0/SPMZoomableUIImageView